# Read Tab delimited file and count the occurrences and delete row

Tags: perl, awk

I am fairly new to programming and trying to resolve this problem. I have the file like this.

```
CHROM    POS     REF     ALT    10_sample.bam   11_sample.bam   12_sample.bam   13_sample.bam   14_sample.bam   15_sample.bam   16_sample.bam 
tg93    77  T   C   T   T   T   T           T
tg93    79  C   -   C       C   C   -   -   
tg93    79  C   G   C   C   C   C   G       C
tg93    80  G   A   G   G   G   G   A   A   G
tg93    81  A   C   A   A   A   A   C   C   C
tg93    86  C   A   C   C   A   A   A   A   C
tg93    105 A   G   A   A   A   A   A   G   A
tg93    108 A   G   A   A   A   A   G   A   A
tg93    114 T   C   T   T   T   T   T   C   T
tg93    131 A   C   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
tg93    136 G   C   C   G   C   C   G   G   G
tg93    150 CTCTC   -       CTCTC       -   CTCTC       CTCTC
```

In this file, in the heading

CHROM - name
POS - position
REF - reference
ALT - alternate
10 - 16_sample.bam - samplesd
I

Now i wanted to see how many times the letter in REF and ALT column occured. If either of them is repeated less than two times, i need to delete that row.

For example 
In the first row, i have 'T' in REF and 'C' in ALT . I see in 7 samples, there are 5 T's and 2 blanks and no C. So i need to delete this row.

In Second row, REF is 'C' and Alt is '-'. Now in seven samples we have 3 C's, 2 '-'s and 2 blanks. So we keep this row as C and - have repeated more than 2 times. 
Always we ignore the blanks while counting

The final file after filtering is

```
#CHROM   POS     REF     ALT    10_sample.bam   11_sample.bam   12_sample.bam   13_sample.bam   14_sample.bam   15_sample.bam   16_sample.bam 
tg93    79  C   -   C       C   C   -   -   
tg93    80  G   A   G   G   G   G   A   A   G
tg93    81  A   C   A   A   A   A   C   C   C
tg93    86  C   A   C   C   A   A   A   A   C
tg93    136 G   C   C   G   C   C   G   G   G
```

I am able to read the columns in to arrays and display them in the code but i am not sure how to start the loops to read the base and count their occurrences and remain the column. Can anyone tell me how i should be proceeding with this? Or it will be helpful if you have any example code i can modify up on.

Comment: I think you could solve this by using hashes instead of arrays, where each key represents a letter and the corresponding value is a counter.  However, one problem is distinguishing the blanks if the field separator is just space.  Are the fields tab separated, maybe?

Comment: Also, how do you interpret the last row?  It seems to follow a different pattern.

Comment: Thank you ikegami.. Thats my fault. 108 should not be in the output.. i edited this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print scalar(<>);                   # Read and output the header.

while (<>) {                        # Read a line.
   chomp;                           # Remove the newline from the line.
   my ($chrom, $pos, $ref, $alt, @samples) =
      split /\t/;                   # Parse the remainder of the line.

   my %counts;                      # Count the occurrences of sample values.
   ++$counts{$_} for @samples;      # e.g. Might end up with $counts{"G"} = 3.

   print "$_\n"                     # Print line if we want to keep it.
      if ($counts{$ref} || 0) >= 2  # ("|| 0" avoids a spurious warning.)
      && ($counts{$alt} || 0) >= 2;
}
```

Output:

```
CHROM    POS     REF     ALT    10_sample.bam   11_sample.bam   12_sample.bam   13_sample.bam   14_sample.bam   15_sample.bam   16_sample.bam 
tg93    79  C   -   C       C   C   -   -   
tg93    80  G   A   G   G   G   G   A   A   G
tg93    81  A   C   A   A   A   A   C   C   C
tg93    86  C   A   C   C   A   A   A   A   C
tg93    136 G   C   C   G   C   C   G   G   G
```

You included 108 in your desired output, but it only has one instance of ALT in the seven samples.

Usage:

```
perl script.pl file.in >file.out
```

Or in-place:

```
perl -i script.pl file
```

Comment: This works perfect.. I am more interested in learning the code than just using it. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: what does print scalar (<>) do here?
"  my ($chrom, $pos, $ref, $alt, @samples) = split /\t/;"
In this line, are you just initializing or is it useful for hashes?
First you read the first line and print the output. "my %counts;" is for initializing the hash.
"++$counts{$_} for @samples;" I couldnt understand what it is doing here.
print "$_ \n" I guess you are printing the first line here with headings
"if ($counts{$ref} || 0) >= 2
      && ($counts{$alt} || 0) >= 2;" What does this if statement doing after the print statemnt?

Comment: cool.. i was thinking to do by using arrays. but with hashes, its neat and easy. Thank you for the answer and great explanation, ikegami.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that does not assume tab separation between fields

```
use IO::All;
my $chrom = "tg93";
my @lines = io('file.txt')->slurp;
foreach(@lines) {
    %letters = ();

    # use regex with backreferences to extract data - this method does not depend on tab separated fields
    if(/$chrom\s+\d+\s+([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])\s{3}([A-Z-\s])/) {

        # initialize hash counts
        $letters{$1} = 0;
        $letters{$2} = 0;

        # loop through the samples and increment the counter when matches are found
        foreach($3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) {
            if ($_ eq $1) {
                ++$letters{$1};
            }
            if ($_ eq $2) {
                ++$letters{$2};
            }
        } 

        # if the counts for both POS and REF are greater than or equal to 2, print the line
        if($letters{$1} >= 2 && $letters{$2} >= 2) {
            print $_;
        }
    }
}
```